# Sort output of awk except for first line?

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, pipe, sort

This is a use case I am continually running into in parsing CSV files.  When it is an inline `awk` script embedded in a shell script, I can use this workaround:

```
myfile="$(mktemp)"
awk '(awk script here)' > "$myfile"
head -1 "$myfile"
sed 1d "$myfile" | sort
rm "$myfile"
```

(Or using appropriate mktemp template for BSD mktemp; GNU works as above.)

However, when writing a full fledged awk script with a shebang `#!/bin/awk -f`, I don't want to have to change it to a shell script just to handle this one factor of sorting the output.

How can I do this in awk?  Or, if there is no native sort function in awk, where can I learn about awk pipelines and how can I use pipelines to accomplish this without changing the shebang?

Comment: For what it's worth, when I am creating CSV files, I always `echo` the headers to the final filename right off the bat.  Then I do all of my sorting in the temporary file, and when I'm done, `cat tmpfile >> final.csv; rm tmpfile`.

Comment: Good to know, but I want to do this with a pure `awk` script.  In cases where the header is going to be parsed and changed in `awk` and change the behavior of the `awk` script (for example, allowing your input columns in arbitrary sequence as long as the headers match pre-defined values in some sequence, and then always outputting a specific column sequence), you need to handle both the header and the content within the same awk script.  Thus my question.  (That is just one example use case; there are others.)

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your output, send the headings to `stderr` could be an option.

Comment: Note that gawk provides two array sorting functions: `asort` to sort by value, and `asorti` to sort by index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example that sorts all lines but the first:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{cmd="sort"}
NR==1{print;next}
{print $1,$2 | cmd}
END{close(cmd)}
```

#### Example

Consider this file:

```
$ cat file
Letter  Value
A       12
D       10
C       15
B       13
```

Then:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Letter  Value
A 12
B 13
C 15
D 10
```

The first input line is the first output line.  The remaining lines are sorted.