# Piping a command's output to a variable in body of awk script

Tags: awk, scripting, sort

Given `inputfile`

```
Cherries:20:100:300
Beans:12:400:500
Tomatoes:32:445:234
Potatoes:24:400:200
Kiwis:23:230:435
```

I have an awk script, named `testscript.script`:

```
BEGIN{ FS = ":" 
print "------------------------"
}

if($3 + $4 > 500) {print $1, $2}
END{
print "------------------------" 
}
```

The output of this script when invoked with `awk -f testscript.script inputfile` is as follows:

```
------------------------
Beans 12
Tomatoes 32
Potatoes 24
Kiwis 23
------------------------
```

I want to sort this list alphabetically  (by name), then store it to a variable so that this list is printable in the **end block** of the awk script.

I.e. the code should look something like this.

```
BEGIN{ FS = ":" 
print "------------------------"
}

*if($3 + $4 > 500) {print $1, $2 | "sort" = variable}
END{
print "------------------------" 
print variable
}
```

And the `print variable` command would yield

```
------------
------------
Beans 12
Kiwis 23
Potatoes 24
Tomatoes 32
```

With the sorted list of items as the variable, and printing it in the END block after the dotted line.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: can you give the input file contents.

Comment: @Kamaraj edited.

Comment: What flavor of awk? Does it have an `asorti` function?

Comment: As of now, I'm using traditional `awk`. I did `man asorti` and didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Since the `sort` command can't terminate until it receives an end-of-file, and you never `close` it, this seems a bit silly.  Why not just add a shell wrapper script to pipe the output of the Awk script through `sort`?

Comment: @Wildcard Apologies, but I am still very very new at scripting in general.. would you mind showing me your shell wrapper example in a full answer? I still need to print the sorted stuff along with the two dashed lines in the original script, not just the sorted stuff.

Comment: @KMoy, [this is relevant](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243491/135943).  I'm having trouble understanding why you would want the sorted list *after* both `------` lines and not before.  Did I get that correctly that that's what you want?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "---------------";awk -F: '$3+$4>500{print $1,$2}' inputfile |sort && echo "---------------"
```

using awk

```
awk -F: '$3+$4>500{Arr[$1]=$2}END{n=asorti(Arr,SArr);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){print SArr[i],Arr[SArr[i]]}}' inputfile
```

Comment: Asorti is not built-in on my interpreter.

Comment: you want to achieve this using awk and store sorted values in variable in awk and print in END section ?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When considering the 'Best' way there is a lot that goes in, I think of best as fastest route meeting my needs. If you are trying to pass a variable beyond the scope of your process I would suggest piping it out to a ram-drive, almost all distros have one, then process your test, and pipe out from that ramdisk after you are done.

On Debian based distros you'll find a ram drive is located at /run/shm, so something like this might meet you needs.

```
cat inputdata.file | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | sort -k 1,1 > /run/shm/datastore.file; echo '------------------------' > datastore2.file; cat /run/shm/datastore.file>>/run/shm/datastore2.file; cat /run/shm/datastore2.file>~/destination.file
```

When the way a process wants to do something is limiting you, just control the formatting with logic and a ramdrive. Dont forget to move your data after processing as anything in /run/shm/* is toast once you reboot.
I hope this helps. Ill keep an eye in case i misunderstood what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can **stick the whole thing into a shell script** and pipe the Awk output to `sort` before it gets printed.

Assuming you want the lines above and below the sorted output (which makes more sense to me visually):

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s\n' ------------------------
cat "$@" | awk -F: '($3 + $4 > 500) {print $1, $2}' | sort
printf '%s\n' ------------------------
```

With this saved in a file called `myscript` set to executable, and running on the `inputfile` you specified by calling:

```
./myscript inputfile
```

The output looks like:

```
------------------------
Beans 12
Kiwis 23
Potatoes 24
Tomatoes 32
------------------------
```

---

Note the use of `"$@"` so that this script can handle multiple file arguments, not just one, just the way Awk can do.

You could also skip using `cat` and just do:

```
awk -F: '($3 + $4 > 500) {print $1, $2}' "$@" | sort
```

However, I personally don't like passing filenames in places where they *could* be interpreted as code.  So I would use `cat` to concatenate the files.